# Twilio calls keep failing-- I think i've been filtered/blacklisted by carrier. What is limit or best practice around this

Tags: twilio, phone-number, twilio-api

TL;DR Twilio calls keep failing-- I think i've been filtered/blacklisted by carrier. What is limit I'm hitting up against and/or best practice around this.

Further description

I'm trying to automate leaving voicemail in an outbound sales effort.

After a handful of calls, any further calls for a given number return 'Failed', with description 'Invalid Phone Number' 13224.

I'm assuming I'm being throttled by the carriers for suspicious/annoying robo-dialing.

Are there rules of thumb for avoiding this blacklisting?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Error 13224](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/13224) does suggest you have invalid numbers rather than are being blocked. The full message is:

> #### Dial: Twilio does not support calling this number or the number is invalid
>
> This error occurs when the provided number is not in E.164 format; for example using local dialing pattern 01234567890 instead of the full E.164 address +441234567890. This can also occur when calls are attempted to non-existent country codes, area codes, or exchanges. For example, there is no +693 country code, no +1238 US area code, and no 555 US exchange.
>
> This can also occur with properly-formatted, valid destinations if none of Twilio’s carrier partners are able to deliver the call; for example a telecom network outage in the phone number’s local area.

Have you ensured the numbers you are dialling are in fact in full [E.164 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164)?